# python pandas special character as delimiter

Tags: python-3.x, csv, pandas

I have a text file with a special character [˛] as a delimiter. I copy pasted this special character as a delimiter in my read_csv command and I am getting the following error:

```
ParserWarning: Falling back to the 'python' engine because the 
separator encoded in utf-8 is > 1 char long, and the 'c' engine does 
not support such separators; you can avoid this warning by specifying 
engine='python'.
  """Entry point for launching an IPython kernel.
```

Any idea how to use a special character while reading a text file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get only warning and solution for remove it is very easy - add `engine='python'`.

[Specifying the parser engine](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#specifying-the-parser-engine):

> Under the hood pandas uses a fast and efficient parser implemented in `C` as well as a python implementation which is currently more feature-complete. Where possible pandas uses the C parser (specified as `engine='c'`), but may fall back to python if C-unsupported options are specified. Currently, C-unsupported options include:

- **sep other than a single character** (e.g. regex separators)
- skipfooter
- sep=None with delim_whitespace=False

> Specifying any of the above options will produce a ParserWarning unless the python engine is selected explicitly using `engine='python'`.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.compat import StringIO

temp=u"""a˛b˛c
1˛3˛5
7˛8˛1
"""
#after testing replace 'StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp), sep="˛", engine='python')
print (df)
   a  b  c
0  1  3  5
1  7  8  1
```